# merging array in CI 3

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to merge two arrays in order to get the data as per my requirement.

I am posting my result, please have a look.

#### First array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 300
            [id] => 2
            [car_id] => 14782

        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 100
            [id] => 3
            [car_id] => 14781

        )    

    [2] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 300
            [id] => 4
            [car_id] => 14783

        )

)
```

#### Second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 9c2e00508cb28eeb1023ef774b122e86
            [car_id] => 14783
            [status] => favourite
        )

)
```

I want to merge the second array into the first one, where the value at key *car_id* matches the equivalent value; otherwise it will return that field as *null*.

#### Required output:

```html
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 300
            [id] => 2
            [car_id] => 14782


        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 100
            [id] => 3
            [car_id] => 14781



        )    

    [2] => Array
        (
            [km_range] => 300
            [id] => 4
            [car_id] => 14783
            [fav_status] => favourite

        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a question about code you wrote that isn't working? If so please include that code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: array_merge is pretty well documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the merge is so specific I would try something like this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $a1):
    foreach ($array2 as $a2):
       if ($a1['car_id'] == $a2['car_id']):
           if ($a2['status'] == "favourite"): 
               $array1[$index]['fav_status'] = "favourite";
           endif;
       endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

You might be able to optimize the code more but this should be very easy to follow...

Comment: Thank you , Previously I have tried in this way , but did not get success.
Now I found my mistakes ,Thanks a lot for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this without using the index syntax is to reference the array elements in the [*foreach*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) [**by-reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) by prepending the ampersand operator:

```
foreach($firstArray as &$nestedArray1) {
    foreach($secondArray as $nestedArray2) {
        if ($nestedArray1['car_id'] == $nestedArray2['car_id']) {
            $nestedArray1['fav_status'] = $nestedArray2['status'];
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action in [this Playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/zHc5Ryi1rx6y9BpR).

Technically you asked about *merging* the arrays. While the keys would be different between the input arrays and the desired output (i.e. "*status*" vs "*fav_status*"), [array_merge()](http://php.net/array_merge) can be used to merge the arrays.

```
if ($nestedArray1['car_id'] == $nestedArray2['car_id']) {
    $nestedArray1 = array_merge($nestedArray1, $nestedArray2);
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/t3POANvJuAUvA9Xp).

Additionally the union operators (i.e. `+`, `+=`) can be used.

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#example-5587)</sup>

```
if ($nestedArray1['car_id'] == $nestedArray2['car_id']) {
    $nestedArray1 += nestedArray1;
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/aOTYzmTSOVczC57X).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#example-5587</sub>